# cannot set JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, linux-mint, environment-variables

I'm running Linux Mint Quiana. I want to run Android Studio and this requires me Java. 
Since i needed NetBeans i decided to install NetBeans with Java 8 bundle from oracle's website. I tried for days to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable but without success. After countless tries and webpages of solutions read. I tried the following:

1. export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_20 (The location where JAva seems to be installed)
2. JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_20 - without the export part and queried echo $JAVA_HOME from another terminal window but it still shows up nothing at all.
3. I tried to modify /etc/environment and add the above line but without any success. And i also tried to edit /etc/profile but still nothing worked. (by without success i mean that the variable didn't get set)

I really don't know what's up with this thing but it seems very complicated for what it should be a simple command in the shell.

When i type :

1. `update-alternatives --query java` I get nothing
2. `java -version` I get:

   The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:

   - default-jre
   - gcj-4.8-jre-headless
   - openjdk-7-jre-headless
   - gcj-4.6-jre-headless
   - openjdk-6-jre-headless
     Try: sudo apt-get install 
     Which seems stupid to me since i can compile stuff with netbeans and this means that JDK is installed properly *somewhere*
3. `which java` tells me nothing at all

I hope this is enough info to solve my issue.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 1):

- Variable definitions in one terminal window are not in the scope of other terminal windows. To define a variable in all terminal windows you need to add it to a shell configuration file. Typically this will be [`~/.bashrc`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles), Bash being the default shell in most distros. You can add a line like [`export JAVA_HOME=/some/path`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Variable_Types) in there to make the `JAVA_HOME` variable available to all shells and scripts run in those shells. (It's only available in shells opened *after* saving `~/.bashrc`; if you want it to be available in an already opened terminal simply run `exec "$SHELL"` to restart your shell.
- [`which java`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_which.htm) looks for an executable called `java` in the colon-separated paths contained in the `PATH` variable, no matter what the value of `JAVA_HOME` is.
- `JAVA_HOME` is used by *Java* applications, not by the shell or the terminal. [Oracle describes it](https://blogs.oracle.com/kto/entry/glossary_for_jdk_builds) as:

  > An environment variable used to trigger the 'java' found in your PATH to use a different JDK image. Unfortunately, not all 'java' startup scripts obey this env variable. It's also used by many java tool startup scripts to determine what 'java' to run, bypassing the 'java' found in the PATH setting. Setting this variable during a JDK build is a bad idea, don't do it.
- The hint about `java` being available in several packages means the directory of the `java` executable (most likely `/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_20/bin` in your case) is not in the `PATH` variable, and can be installed from the distro packages listed. You'll need to add the directory to the `PATH` variable like `export PATH="$PATH"':/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_20/bin'` in a shell startup file like above.

Does that clarify things?

Comment: I understand what you said. I followed your steps and now after a reboot when i do `echo $JAVA_HOME i do get the right path but when i try to launch android studio, i get the same error. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Android Studio probably needs to be configured separately. After checking the AS configuration documentation and searching for the error message you're getting you may want to add a question here with the specific error message, how you configured it, and other relevant information.

Comment: It just states that it needs java(jdk) to start running which i can confirm since i had it installed previously on the same OS but for some reason now i can't get JAVA_HOME to work properly. I added it in my PATH variable but i don't know what else should i do. Also `which java` tells me nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the Java version provided with NetBeans on Oracle's website, after digging around some more, i managed to find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474963/android-studio-tools-jar-file-is-not-present-in-classpath/17827697#17827697) that solved the issue in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable, I had to reboot my Windows 7 for my environment variable to take effect. Usually just reopening the terminal would do it.